# How to Click a desired pixels on the screen?

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to make a program that clicks the specified pixel on the screen.

I can do a screen capture like this

```java
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle)
```

but I don't know how to make a procedure on this image.

What can I use to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Look at the JabaDocs for BufferedImage, you can scan through the pixel data using getRGB (or something like that). Remember though, a screen doesn’t always start at 0x0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on a specific Pixel with the mouse using **Robot** class in java

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class MouseClicker {

    static Robot rb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            rb = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while creating object" + e);
        }


   rb.mouseMove(1360, 768); //this method takes two parameters (Height, Width)
   rb.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);//this method takes one parameter (BUTTON) to press it
   rb.delay(10); //this is the delay between every press
   rb.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);//this method takes one parameter (BUTTON) to release it

    }

}
```

For more refrance you can see the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)